# wpdb print all post meta

Tags: query, wpdb

I create query to make an output all meta value from meta key `select_analyst` but if I put OR to include two `post_status` it's print all postmeta. Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

If I put only one post status it is work but I need another `post_status`.

My query:

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare('
    SELECT DISTINCT pm.meta_value FROM %1$s pm
    LEFT JOIN %2$s p ON p.ID = pm.post_id
    WHERE pm.meta_key = "%3$s" 
    AND p.post_status = "%4$s"
    OR p.post_status = "%5$s"
    AND p.post_type = "%6$s"
    ORDER BY "%3$s"',
    $wpdb->postmeta,
    $wpdb->posts,
    'select_analyst', 
    'new',
    'pending_review',          
    $post_type
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a WordPress question as it's just standard SQL, so it doesn't really belong here, but I have some points to make about your use of `$wpdb->prepare()` so will answer the question.

So, let's look at your `WHERE` clause, isolated, with values substituted, and indented to reflect how it will be interpreted:

```
WHERE 
    pm.meta_key = "select_analyst" AND p.post_status = "new" OR 
    p.post_status = "pending_review" AND p.post_type = "post_type"
```

This is returning `meta_value` for rows that meet the following conditions:

- `meta_key` is `select_analyst` *and* `post_status` is `new`
- *or* `post_status` is `pending_review` and `post_type` is your post type.

Notice the second condition doesn't specify a meta key, so you'll get `meta_values` for all posts that are `pending_review`.

You need to format your conditions so that you're querying:

- `meta_key` is `select_analyst`
- `post_type` is your post type
- `post_status` is `new` *or* `pending_review`

The SQL for that would be

```
WHERE
    pm.meta_key = 'select_analyst' AND 
    p.post_type = 'post_type' AND
    p.post_status IN ('new', 'pending_review' )
```

So your full query should be:

```
$query = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT 
        DISTINCT pm.meta_value 
    FROM 
        $wpdb->postmeta pm
    LEFT JOIN 
        $wpdb->posts p ON p.ID = pm.post_id
    WHERE 
        pm.meta_key = 'select_analyst' AND
        p.post_type = $post_type AND
        p.post_status IN ('new', 'pending_review')
    ORDER BY
        pm.meta_value"
);
```

A couple of other changes I made:

- You don't need to prepare the statement. There's no unsafe user input being put into the query. The only reason you'd want to do that is to save writing the key out multiple times, but you can always just put the variable directly in the statement if it's not from unsafe input. You weren't even using any of the variables multiple times (except the meta key, see below) so this was unncessary for your query.
- You were ordering by the literal value `'select_analyst'`, which isn't going to do anything. I assume you wanted to sort by the meta value, so I did that.

Also note how indenting the code to reflect the structure of the query makes it much easier to spot these sorts of issues.

Comment: It's really work. Thank you.I appreciate the good explanation you have shown me. Your life is worthy of emulation and I’m proud to be able to learn from you.